# Struggling to change a container width by % instead of px

Tags: html, css, class

I have a little test page here.
http://andynguy.com/test.html

I'm using slick carousal, but I'd like the width of the carousal to be 80% of the windows width. I can adjust it by px, but it does not get affected when I use %.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected your web page and believe I have something that will work for you. In your slick.css file, look for your `.slick-slider` selector, just add in the following two properties/values for `width` and `margin`:

```
.slick-slider {

width: 80%; /* Add a width of 80% */
margin: auto; /* Add a margin of auto */

position: relative;
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-ms-touch-action: pan-y;
touch-action: pan-y;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
```